# How to know if a found word is part of a string or is a function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Sorry! I couldn't think about a better title to my question

My problem is this: I've a javascript ... script, read from a data base. Now, this script have al sorts of ifs, whiles, function calls etc. Before executing the script, I want to replace some specific function names, so I need to do a replace in the script looking for that word. My problem is that when that word IS NOT an intended function call, but a text contained in a wider string, it is replaced nonetheless.

Let me give an example to be more clear:

```
var actualFunction = function(){
  return 1;
}

console.log(myfunction);

var s = "I was talking about myfunction with my colleagues...";
```

In this example, I want to replace "myfunction" when used as a function (or object), but don't replace "myfunction" when it is inside another string. The desired result will be this:

```
var actualFunction = function(){
  return 1;
}

console.log(actualFunction);

var s = "I was talking about myfunction with my colleagues...";
```

So I only want to replace "console.log(myfunction);" with "console.log(actualFunction", and leave alone the text inside the "s" variable.

The find method will find two occurences of "myfunction", but it must recognize that the second occurence is inside a longer string, and leave it alone.

I hope that I made myself clear :) and thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't do that. Simply output more javascript like `var myfunction = function(){ actualFunction(); };`, **before** all the code.

Comment: I can't imagine why you want to do this, but if you really want to, then you need a JS parser to transform the JS.

Comment: As pointed out by @torazaburo this would require a parser. Did you consider using a callback or putting a statement on top which assigns the desired function to myfunction?

Comment: you find all strings, store them in a list, then replace every string by "some marker NUM", where NUM is their position. Then you do your replacement, and replace the string in the list back afterward.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I actually don't want to, but the client insists in doing that.

Comment: @Laerion The client **ISN'T ALWAYS RIGHT**. This time, he is far from it. He lost it, for sure. Ask to edit the data.

Comment: Clients have reasons for doing something. In other words, there is something they are trying to accomplish. They may suggest an approach, but sometimes it is the wrong approach, or a non-feasible approach, or an approach which requires unreasonable amounts of work. In that case, you have a discussion about that with the client. The first thing you should do is have the client explain the context and the end goal to you. What is the context and end goal here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with regular expressions, checking if the "word" was inside single or double quotes, if so, is a string and I don't replace, if not, the word is replaced. I know this isn't ideal, but it works well. Thanks to all :)